# How can I remove extra top-bottom spacing from UIAlertView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Using UIAlertView to create following alert, which is showing extra spaces in top & bottom As seen in Image 1.
I want to remove this spacings as seen in Image 2.
Please suggest any solution.

**My code for alert : Using iOS 7.1**

```
 - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame Cancel:(NSString *)CancelValue Set:(NSString *)SetValue Tag:(int)TagValue Array:(NSMutableArray *)ArrayValue
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self)
    {
        // Initialization code

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

        UIView *vwAlert = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 380)];
        [alert addSubview:vwAlert];

        UITableView *table = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 0, 280, 350) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
        table.dataSource = self;
        table.delegate = self;
        table.scrollEnabled = NO;
        table.tag = TagValue;
        [table setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
        [vwAlert addSubview:table];

        aryTitle = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Sort Habits",@"Habit Records",@"Category", nil];
        vwAlert.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 170);
        table.frame = CGRectMake(20, 0, 280, vwAlert.frame.size.height);

        btnCancel.hidden=YES;
        btnSet.hidden=YES;

        UIImageView *imgVw = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(250, 2, 40, 40)];
        imgVw.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_filter_clear"];
        [vwAlert addSubview:imgVw];

        UIButton *btnClearAll = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
        btnClearAll.frame = CGRectMake(235, 0, 60, 40);
        [btnClearAll addTarget:self action:@selector(funClearAll:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [vwAlert addSubview:btnClearAll];

        [table reloadData];
        [alert setValue:vwAlert forKey:@"accessoryView"];
        [alert show];
    }
    return self;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 3;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [aryRestore objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row)];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir Next" size:16];
    return cell;
}
```

**Image 1**
[image]

**Image 2**
[image]

Comment: Don't use the `UIAlertView` like this, it is not support by apple. As clearly stated in the `UIAlertView` documentation you should not modify the view hierarchy is private an should not be modified.

Comment: why cannot you use tableview for that.why do you waste time with alertview customization

Comment: Why do you abuse `UIAlertView`, use view controller and custom transition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create custom alertview like below.

***CustomAlertView.h***

```
@interface CustomAlertView:UIAlertView {}
```

***CustomAlertView.m***

```
// override
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    for(UIView * sub in self.subviews)
    {
        [sub removeFromSuperview];
    }
    // this removeFromSuperview will clear all thing such as background view and buttons

    // do something
}
```

Now in your view controller import this customalertview as below.

```
#import "CustomAlertView.h"
```

And then instead of

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
```

use

```
CustomAlertView *alert = [[CustomAlertView alloc]
```

### Note

Using UIAlertView for what you are doing is not right. I would suggest to use popover like [KGModal](https://github.com/kgn/KGModal).

Comment: @ParmarS : you don't need to call drawRect. Just create new .h & .m file which extends UIAlertview and use `CustomAlertView *alert`. That's it...